# Different data show in different button click event in same table view

Tags: ios, json

I am doing parsing and i have two url in first url contains city and the second url contains enters .For this i use same parsing  method but in didfinishwithloading i give two url.I want when i click first button then it shows city and on second button it should be show enters.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (_CitySelect.touchInside==TRUE)
    {

    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData options:0 error:0];
       NSArray *city_info =[json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info)
    {

        NSArray *vlcc_city_name=[dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_city_name"];
        arrayname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:vlcc_city_name, nil];

        NSString *Vlcc_city = [arrayname componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
        NSLog(@"%@",Vlcc_city);

       // NSLog(@"%@",vlcc_city_name);
    }

    }

else if (Touch==FALSE)

{
    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:WebData options:0 error:0];
    NSArray *city_info =[json objectForKey:@"city_info"];
    for(NSDictionary *dic in city_info)
    {

        NSArray *vlcc_center_name=[dic objectForKey:@"vlcc_center_name"];
        Centers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:vlcc_center_name, nil];



        NSLog(@"%@",vlcc_center_name);


}
}
 **"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/getcitynames.php
"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/getareanames.php?cityname=Vlcc_city"**
In second url , in vlccCity i just copy in to city.
```

Comment: make Your response Array  global as you need to display to the different button.

Comment: Could any one give me and??